# XSLT to Produce HTML Output ignoring XML syntax

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the following xml configuration file in my file system.

- XML Configuration File Name : applId_maps.xml

The file has below contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <APPIDMAP>
    <Map APPName="Test1" APID="1"/>
    <Map APPName="Test2" APID="2"/>
    <Map APPName="Test3" APID="3"/>
  </APPIDMAP>
</config>
```

I am writing an XSLT code to store the file content in a variable and output the variable in a HTML format in web browser.

Below is my XSLT code to generate the required HTML format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="AppIDConfigFile" select="document('applId_maps.xml')"/>

    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table style="width:100%" border="1" >
                <tr bgcolor="#A9E2F3">
                        <th>Application ID Mapping Configuration File</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <pre><code><xsl:copy-of select="$AppIDConfigFile"/></code></pre>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The use of

```
<pre><code><xsl:copy-of select="$AppIDConfigFile"/></code></pre>
```

is not producing the XML file in the browser output.

Is there any other way for html to ignore the XML syntax present in the XSLT variable and out put the content of variable as it is.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you want that to work with?

Comment: I am currently working with XSLT 1.0 and using IBM DataPower as the XSLT processor.

Comment: Check its documentation whether it has a function to serialize a node to a string.

Comment: Hello Martin, You suggestion worked like charm. DataPower documentation provides the function "serialize" to produce the node to byte stream. Thanks for your valuable input.